# Convert Rows Into Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

### **Table A**

```
ID  COLA    
-----------------------
A   value1      
B   value1
C   value1
```

### Table B

```
ID  DETAIL_ID   COL_X   COL_Y
A   0           foo     foo
A   1           bar     bar
B   0           foo     foo
```

My expected out is something like

```
ID  COLA    COL_X_0 COL_X_1 COL_Y_0 COL_Y_1
A   value1  foo     bar     foo     bar
B   value1  foo     NULL    foo     NULL
C   value1  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

It means the rows of table B  will be column values based on DETAIL_ID column.

I tried to write queries for this , but can't succeed due to following.
Number of DetailID values will NOT be fixed-length.It means I can't hard-coded the name of the columns.

Comment: Which version of SQL? 2005+ supports pivots

Comment: @Kai -- 
For this you can write pl/sql and in this you have to use cursor and by this you can add column as much you are getting distinct value in this column or if you just want to disply you can display in pl/sql DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (it is a oracle pl/sql function).. but corresponding sql-server function you can use to display for different values in corresponding different columns

Comment: If you don't know the final number of columns in advance, you can't do that in a standard SQL query.  Instead you need to write dynamic sql to do the pivot for you.  I'd search StackOverflow for `dynamic sql pivot`  (@Pratik: This is SQL Server, not Oracle.)

Comment: @BugFinder, I think, here I can't use pivots, since I may NOT know the number of columns in advance. It means, I do NOT know which DETAIL_ID should be filtered in advance.

Comment: @ pratik garg , Thanks. I know , this may be done in cursor. But, the problem is, the queries will become somewhat complex and I've to execute this query so many times and tables have lots of data.

Comment: If you have to execute the query often, is creating another table for the pivoted view and using triggers to update it an option? It will be horribly hacky, but it might be the only way to get reasonable performance (dynamic SQL to create a variable-#-of-columns pivot is not going to perform fast at all).

The other idea I have is to use the same table, but instead of triggering on every DML statement, schedule the dynamic SQL to run periodically. Depends on how much you need the data to be right up to date.

Comment: @Dems, Thanks . Let me check dynamic sql pivot. But, as you can see in my example, there's no aggregation function needed. Can I use pivot without aggregation function??

Comment: @Simon Righarts, Thanks.I think, having extra table will NOT be an option. As you see, I may NOT know how many DETAIL_IDs will be there in advance, and hence, can't foresee how many columns needed.

Comment: Firstly, Simon said, if you have to execute it often, then cache it into another table which you update less frequently.  Also, you should be able to pivot, it will just be a little more complicated. You should be able to do something it just wont run fast. (in the pivot section rather than list specific values, you should be able to insert another select clause)

Comment: You should be able to write a trigger on TableA to add a column (or two columns) to TableB. Keeping track of how many columns you've already added might be annoying, but it's certainly doable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190227%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx specifies that ALTER TABLE can't be used in a DML trigger against the target table of the trigger - so in this case, a trigger on TableA can't run ALTER TABLE TableA, but it should be able to run ALTER TABLE TableB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL queries must specify the columns of the result set.  That's fundamental to SQL.  Even PIVOT requires that your query specify the columns before you send it to the RDBMS.

For that reason, it's difficult and error-prone to create a query that returns rows as columns as you describe, and can adapt as needed to any number of columns.

**Handling dynamic columns must be a two-stage procedure.**

One option is to make the two stages be:

1. Write application code to build the SQL query dynamically, based on the distinct values found in the data.  This requires an extra query to discover what values exist so you can build the query.
2. Execute the SQL query and retrieve the results.

The other option is to make the two stages be:

1. Run a more plain SQL query, that fetches rows as rows, as they are stored in the database.
2. Write application code to post-process the results, collecting individual values from rows into an expanding set of columns based on the values found.  This does not require an extra query as the first design does.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the exact output you described and you can add more columns if needed

```
DECLARE @a table (id char, cola varchar(10))
DECLARE @b table (id char, detail_id int, colx char(3), coly char(3))

INSERT @a values('A', 'value1'),('B', 'value2'),('C','value3')
INSERT @b values('A', 0, 'foo', 'foo'),('A', 1, 'bar', 'bar'),
('B',0, 'foo','foo')--,('A', 2, 'bar', 'bar') -- add this for extra columns

CREATE TABLE ##t(id char, detail_id tinyint, colvalue char(3), col varchar(8), cola varchar(10))
DECLARE @columns varchar(max)=''
DECLARE @sqlstring varchar(1000)

;WITH a as (
SELECT a.id, a.cola, b.detail_id, colx, coly,
'col_x_' + cast(detail_id as varchar) col_a,
'col_y_' + cast(detail_id as varchar) col_b
FROM @a a LEFT JOIN @b b on a.id = b.id
) 
INSERT ##t
SELECT id, detail_id, colx, col_a, cola FROM a
UNION
SELECT id, detail_id, coly, col_b, cola FROM a
ORDER BY 4,2

SELECT @columns = coalesce(@columns, '') +',[' + col + ']'
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT col, detail_id FROM ##t where not col is null
) a 

SET @columns = stuff(@columns, 1,1,'')

SET @sqlstring = 
'SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, cola, col, colvalue FROM ##t 
) b
PIVOT(max(colvalue) FOR col 
in(
'+@columns+'))AS p order by 1'

EXEC(@sqlstring)

DROP TABLE ##t
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join table A and B on B.DETAIL_ID == A.ID ?? Or is that too simple?