# MySQL: how to convert to EAV - Part 3?

Tags: mysql, database, entity-attribute-value

Previous Related Posts:

- [MySQL: how to convert to EAV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020661/mysql-how-to-convert-to-eav)
- [MySQL: how to convert to EAV - Part 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034212/mysql-how-to-convert-to-eav-part-2)

Given a table:

```
TABLE: foo
===============================
| id | first_name | last_name |
===============================
| 1  | John       | Doe       |
| 2  | Jane       | Smith     |
| 3  | Ronald     | McDonald  |
-------------------------------
```

How do I take this table and convert it to these tables (an EAV implementation)?:

```
TABLE: attribute
===========================
| id | fk_id | attribute  |
===========================
| 1  | 100   | first_name |
| 2  | 100   | last_name  |
---------------------------

TABLE: value
=========================================
| id | attribute_id | row_id | value    |
=========================================
| 1  | 1            | 1      | John     |
| 2  | 2            | 1      | Doe      |
| 3  | 1            | 2      | Jane     |
| 4  | 2            | 2      | Smith    |
| 5  | 1            | 3      | Ronald   |
| 6  | 2            | 3      | McDonald |
-----------------------------------------
```

NOTES:

- attribute.fk_id will be provided.
- value.row_id is used to identify how the values are grouped as records in the original table.

UPDATE: Also, how do I query the EAV tables so that I can make it look like table `foo` again.

Comment: Yup, something like take. More playtime with EAVs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only hope is if you use the `foo` table. `bar` is essentially useless without the ID.

Try something like this (assuming `attribute.id` is an auto-increment primary key)

```
INSERT INTO `attribute` (`fk_id`, `attribute`)
VALUES (100, 'first_name');

INSERT INTO `value` (`attribute_id`, `row_id`, `value`)
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), `id`, `first_name`
FROM `foo`;

INSERT INTO `attribute` (`fk_id`, `attribute`)
VALUES (100, 'last_name');

INSERT INTO `value` (`attribute_id`, `row_id`, `value`)
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), `id`, `last_name`
FROM `foo`;
```

To reconstruct the `foo` table, try this

```
SELECT
    `fn`.`row_id` AS `id`,
    `fn`.`value` AS `first_name`,
    `ln`.`value` AS `last_name`
FROM `value` `fn`
INNER JOIN `attribute` `fn_a`
    ON `fn`.`attribute_id` = `fn_a`.`id`
    AND `fn_a`.`attribute` = 'first_name'
INNER JOIN `value` `ln`
    ON `fn`.`row_id` = `ln`.`row_id`
INNER JOIN `attribute` `ln_a`
    ON `ln`.`attribute_id` = `ln_a`.`id`
    AND `ln_a`.`attribute` = 'last_name'
```

<sub>Ergh, thanks for reminding me why I hate this pattern</sub>

Comment: OK, I can get rid of `bar`. Is there one query to convert the EAV back into the original table? Right now, I just want to do a SELECT, not INSERT the results.

Answer (score 2):

I give +1 to @Phil's solution for populating the EAV table.  Insert one attribute at a time.

Here's another solution to reverse an EAV transformation:

```
SELECT v.row_id AS id,
  MAX(IF(a.attribute='first_name',v.value,NULL)) AS first_name,
  MAX(IF(a.attribute='last_name',v.value,NULL)) AS last_name
FROM value v INNER JOIN attribute a
  ON v.attribute_id = a.id 
GROUP BY v.row_id
```

Except that by using EAV, you've put all your values into a column of VARCHAR(255) or whatever, so you have lost information about the respective data types of the original columns.

There's really no way to do it "dynamically" without hard-coding the attribute names, either as joins as @Phil shows, or as columns as I show.  It's essentially the same problem as [trying to write dynamic pivot queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813952/convert-rows-into-columns-in-sql/6823293#6823293).

I have written more about EAV in my presentation [Practical Object-Oriented Models in SQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql) and in my book, [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: Your presentation and book links are the same. Also, I think you are missing some parentheses